# Unity3d Shader does not take alpha channel of color into effect

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, shaderlab

So i managed to put together this shader that will render a outline of a object and render the rest of the object with some transparency. Here is the entire code:

```
Shader "Outlined/Outline with transperancy" {
    Properties {
        _OutlineColor ("Outline Color1", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
        _Outline ("Outline width", Range (0.0, 0.3)) = .005
        _MainTex ("Maintexture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color("Main Color",Color) = (0,0,0,0)
    }

CGINCLUDE
#include "UnityCG.cginc"

struct appdata {
    float4 vertex : POSITION;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
};

struct v2f {
    float4 pos : POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;

};
struct v2ft

{

    float4  pos : SV_POSITION;

    float2  uv : TEXCOORD0;

};
uniform float _Outline;
uniform float4 _OutlineColor;
uniform float4 _Color;
v2f vert(appdata v) {
    // just make a copy of incoming vertex data but scaled according to normal direction
    v2f o;
    o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);

    float3 norm   = mul ((float3x3)UNITY_MATRIX_IT_MV, v.normal);
    float2 offset = TransformViewToProjection(norm.xy);

    o.pos.xy += offset * o.pos.z * _Outline;
    o.color = _OutlineColor;
    o.color.w = _Color.w;
    return o;
}
ENDCG

    SubShader {
    Tags{ "Queue" = "Transparent" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
    LOD 200
        Pass {
            Name "BASE"
            Cull Back
            Blend Zero One

            // uncomment this to hide inner details:
            //Offset -8, -8

            SetTexture [_OutlineColor] {
                ConstantColor (0,0,0,0)
                Combine constant
            }
        }

        // note that a vertex shader is specified here but its using the one above
        Pass {
            Name "OUTLINE"
            Tags { "LightMode" = "Always" }
            Cull Front

            // you can choose what kind of blending mode you want for the outline
            //Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha // Normal
            Blend One One // Additive
            //Blend One OneMinusDstColor // Soft Additive
            //Blend DstColor Zero // Multiplicative
            //Blend DstColor SrcColor // 2x Multiplicative

CGPROGRAM
#pragma vertex vert
#pragma fragment frag

half4 frag(v2f i) :COLOR {
    return i.color;
}
ENDCG
        }
        Pass{
        Name "Transperancy"
    CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert

            #pragma fragment frag

            #pragma multi_compile_builtin

            #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest



            #include "UnityCG.cginc"


            v2ft vert(appdata_base v)

            {

                v2ft o;

                o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);

                o.uv = v.texcoord.xy;

                return o;

            }



            sampler2D _MainTex;

            //float4 _Color;



            fixed4 frag(v2ft i) : COLOR

            {

                fixed4 result = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * _Color;
                return result;

            }

    ENDCG

}

    }

    Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```

It all works well except that the alpha of the color that tints the main texture in the final pass has no effect at all. The tint itself works.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the Transparency pass with the  following :

```
        Pass{
    ZWrite On
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
    ColorMask RGB
    Material{
    Diffuse[_Color]
    Ambient[_Color]
}
Lighting On
SetTexture[_MainTex]{
    Combine texture * primary DOUBLE, texture * primary
}
}
```